# Get file names in awk result

Tags: command-line, awk, filenames

I have many files in a location where I need to list file names in which 32th column has value more than 3000.

This is the command that gives me those records:

```
awk -F, '$32 > 3000' *
```

Now can anyone tell me how can I get names of those files that have these records.

Answer (score 7):

Just make use of `FILENAME` built-in variable:

```
awk -F, '$32 > 3000{print FILENAME; nextfile}' *
```