# Why does awk stop and wait if the filename contains = and how to work around that?

Tags: awk, filenames

```
awk 'processing_script_here' my=file.txt
```

seems to stop and wait indefinitely...
What's going on here and how do I make it work ?

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/475013/308316

Comment: To expand on mosvy's answer (and basically answer your question): `awk '{ ... }' ./my=file.txt`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As [Chris says](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490526/117549), arguments of the form `variablename=anything` are treated as variable assignment (that are performed at the time the arguments are processed as opposed to the (newer) `-v var=value` ones which are performed before the `BEGIN` statements) instead of input file names.

That can be useful in things like:

```
awk '{print $1}' FS=/ RS='\n' file1 FS='\n' RS= file2
```

Where you can specify a different `FS`/`RS` per file. It's also commonly used in:

```
awk '!file1_processed{a[$0]; next}; {...}' file1 file1_processed=1 file2
```

Which is a safer version of:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next}; {...}' file1 file2
```

(which doesn't work if `file1` is empty)

But that gets in the way when you have files whose name contains `=` characters.

Now, that's only a problem when what's left of the first `=` is a valid `awk` variable name.

What constitutes a valid variable name in `awk` is stricter than in `sh`.

POSIX requires it to be something like:

```
[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

With only characters of the portable character set.  However, the `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` of Solaris 11 at least is not compliant in that regard and allows any alphabetical characters in the locale in variable names, not just a-zA-Z.

So an argument like `x+y=foo` or `=bar` or `./foo=bar` is still treated as an input file name and not an assignment as what's left of the first `=` is not a valid variable name. An argument like `Stéphane=Chazelas.txt` may or may not, depending on the `awk` implementation and locale.

That's why with awk, it's recommended to use:

```bsh
awk '...' ./*.txt
```

instead of

```
awk '...' *.txt
```

for instance to avoid the problem if you can't guarantee the name of the `txt` files won't contain `=` characters.

Also, beware that an argument like `-vfoo=bar.txt` may be treated as an option if you use:

```
awk -f file.awk -vfoo=bar.txt
```

(also applies to `awk '{code}' -vfoo=bar.txt` with the `awk` from busybox versions prior to 1.28.0, see [corresponding bug report](https://bugs.busybox.net/show_bug.cgi?id=9861)).

Again, using `./*.txt` works around that (using a `./` prefix also helps with a file called `-` which otherwise `awk` understands as meaning *standard input* instead).

That's also why

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
```

shebangs don't really work. While the `var=value` ones can be worked around by *fixing* the `ARGV` values (add a `./` prefix) in a `BEGIN` statement:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++)
    if (ARGV[i] ~ /^[_[:alpha:]][_[:alnum:]]*=/)
      ARGV[i] = "./" ARGV[i]
}
# rest of awk script
```

That won't help with the option ones as those ones are seen by `awk` and not the `awk` script.

One potential cosmetic issue with using that `./` prefix is it ends up in `FILENAME`, but you can always use `substr(FILENAME, 3)` to strip it if you don't want it.

The GNU implementation of `awk` fixes all those issues with its `-E` option.

After `-E`, gawk expects only the path of the `awk` script (where `-` still means stdin) and then a list of input file paths only (and there, not even `-` is treated specially).

It's specially designed for:

```
#! /usr/bin/gawk -E
```

shebangs where the list of arguments are always input files (note that you're still free to edit that `ARGV` list in a `BEGIN` statement).

You can also use it as:

```
gawk -e '...awk code here...' -E /dev/null *.txt
```

We use `-E` with an empty script (`/dev/null`) just to make sure those `*.txt` afterwards are always treated as input files, even if they contain `=` characters.

Comment: I don't see how the explicit path ending up in FILENAME is a problem. Either the awk script is general, in which case it should handle all kind of paths ending up in FILENAME (including but not limited to `../foo`, `/path/to/foo` and paths that are in a different encoding) -- in which case `substr(FILENAME,3)` won't be enough, or it's a one shot script where the user basically knows what the filenames are -- in which case s/he probably shouldn't bother with any of them containing `=` either ;-)

Comment: @mosvy I don't think it states so much that `./` is a problem, but that it may be undesirable under certain conditions, such as cases where filename has to be included in the output, in which case `./` should be redundant and unnecessary, so you'll need to get rid of it somehow.  Here's at least [one example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/177495/85039). As for user knowing what filenames are - well, in this case we also know what filename is, but `=` still gets in the way of proper processing. So can leading `-` get in the way.

Comment: @mosvy, yes the idea is that you want to use the `./` prefix to work around that `awk` (mis)feature but then you end up with a that `./` on output which you may want to strip. See [how to check if the first line of file contain a specific string?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/480733) as an example.

Comment: Is not only the local (relative to this directory) `./` but also the global (absolute path) `/` which makes awk interpret the argument as a file.

Answer (score 22):

In most versions of awk, arguments after the program to execute are either:

1. A file
2. An assignment of the form `x=y`

Since your filename is being interpreted as case #2, awk is still waiting for something to read on stdin (since it doesn't perceive that there has been any filename passed).

Portably, this behaviour is [documented in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/awk.html):

> Either of the following two types of argument can be intermixed:
>
> - file: A pathname of a file that contains the input to be read, which is matched against the set of patterns in the program. If no file operands are specified, or if a file operand is '-', the standard input shall be used.
> - assignment: An operand that begins with an underscore or alphabetic character from the portable character set (see the table in the Base Definitions volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, Section 6.1, Portable Character Set), followed by a sequence of underscores, digits, and alphabetics from the portable character set, followed by the '=' character, shall specify a variable assignment rather than a pathname.

As such, portably, you have a few options (#1 is likely the least intrusive):

1. Use `awk ... ./my=file`, which sidesteps this since `.` is not "an underscore or alphabetic character from the portable character set".
2. Put the file on stdin using `awk ... < my=file`. However, this doesn't work well with multiple files.
3. Make a hardlink to the file temporarily, and use that. You can do something like `ln my=file my_file`, and then use `my_file` as normal. No copying will be performed, and both files will be backed by the same data and inode metadata. After using it, it's safe to remove the link created as the number of references to the inode will still be greater than 0.

Comment: Doesn't `./my=file`  work?  `% awk 'processing_script_here' ./my=file.txt
awk: fatal: cannot open file ./my=file.txt' for reading (No such file or directory).`  This should be portable because `./my` isn't a valid variable name, so shouldn't be parsed that way.

Comment: @StephenHarris `./` works just fine with either bash or dash on Ubuntu.

Comment: As that POSIX text says, the problem is only when the first `=` is preceded by _an underscore or alphabetic character from the portable character set (see the table in the Base Definitions volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, Section 6.1, Portable Character Set), followed by a sequence of underscores, digits, and alphabetics from the portable character set_. so a file path like `++foo=bar.txt` or `=foo` or `./foo=bar` are all OK as that `.` or `+` is not a `[_a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: @StephenHarris Ah yes! You're quite right.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy awk is external to the shell, so it doesn't matter which you use. `./my=file` will be passed through verbatim.

Comment: `awk ... < myfile` doesn't make any difference with regards to _seeking_ (not sure why `awk` would want to seek anyway). That does mean however that the name of the file is not available in `FILENAME`.

Comment: @ChrisDown I know, I'm just relating my results to Stephen's comment.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas FYI, with `strace awk '{print $1,$2}' < /etc/passwd` there are instances of `lseek()` going through several system files, such as `/proc/self/maps` but nothing related to the actual file itself.

Comment: @ChrisDown There may be a confusion that `stdin` is not seekable, which isn't quite the case as shown in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337739/what-is-the-difference-between-cat-file-binary-and-binary-file/337750#337750

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, same for `awk '{print $1,$2}' /etc/passwd`. The point is that having the shell open  the file as opposed to awk doesn't make any difference as to whether it makes it seekable or not. Actually, in `awk '{exit}' < /etc/passwd`, you'd expect `awk` to seek back  to the end of the first record upon that `exit` to make sure it leaves the position within stdin there. POSIX requires that. `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` does it on Solaris, but neither `gawk` nor `mawk` seem to do it on GNU/Linux.

Comment: Good succinct answer. My only quibble would be the suggestion of using hard links, or any form of link at all. The ./ trick is simple, correct, and works in lots of other similar cases as well.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas where does POSIX require `awk` to seek back to the end of the current record on `exit`? It's true that solaris' awk does that, but that's pretty dumb IMHO, because it introduces a difference in behavior when the stdin isn't seekable, eg. in `ksh -c 'printf "1st\n2nd\n3rd\n" > f; exec < <(cat f); awk "{exit}"; echo AFTER; cat'` vs. `... ; exec <f; ...`.

Comment: @mosvy, see _INPUT FILES_ section at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_04 It's useful in a number of usage patterns that only make sense with regular files like when you want to truncate a file or write data into it at a position identified by `awk` that way.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks. But I wouldn't implement that either if I were the maintainer of gawk, mawk or bwk ;-)

Comment: @mosvy, if they were using stdio, that would be done automatically. Not implementing POSIX requirements is just making everyone's life harder when try to write portable code. I'll report those non-conformance. Note that there's also the case of `awk 'FNR==1{system("cat")}' < file` which even Solaris' /usr/xpg4/bin/awk doesn't handle _"properly"_ (the POSIX spec should probably be clarified first about  that one).

Answer (score 4):

To quote [gawk documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) ( note emphasis added ):

> Any additional arguments on the command line are normally treated as input files to be processed in the order specified. However, **an argument that has the form var=value, assigns the value value to the variable var—it does not specify a file at all.**

Why does the command stop and wait ? Because in the form `awk 'processing_script_here' my=file.txt` *there is no file specified* by the above definition - `my=file.txt` is interpreted as variable assignment, and if there's no file defined `awk` will read stdin ( also evident from `strace` which shows that awk in such command is waiting on `read(0,'...)` syscall.

This is also documented in [POSIX awk specifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/awk.html), see OPERANDS section and *assignments* part of that )

Variable assignment is evident in `awk '{print foo}' foo=bar /etc/passwd` that value of `foo` is printed for every line in /etc/passwd. Specifying `./foo=bar` or full path however does work.

Note that running `strace` on `awk '1' foo=bar` as well as checking with `cat foo=bar` shows that this is awk-specific issue, and execve does show filename as argument passed, so shells have nothing to do with env variable assignments in this case.

Additionally, please note that `awk '...script...' foo=bar` will not cause environment variable creation by shell, since environment variable assignments should be preceding a command to take effect. See [POSIX Shell Grammar Rules](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_10_02), point number 7. Additionally this can be verified via `awk '{print ENVIRON["foo"]}' foo=bar /etc/passwd`